# error in angular js directive when open a modal

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, modal-dialog

i am using a custom directive in my header to open a login modal on click a function from directive controller from header(its working fine and modal open successfully). in modal html  i also have a button (sign in) when i click sign in its call an another function(RegistrationModal) from directive but its throw a error not is not opened,please check the code

```
 .directive('header', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        templateUrl: HTML.HEADER,
        scope: true,
        controller: function ($scope, $rootScope, $http, $templateCache,$compile) {
            $scope.RegistrationModal = function () {
              $(".modal").remove();
              $(".modal-backdrop").remove();
              $http.get(HTML.SIGN_UP, {cache: $templateCache}).success(function (data) {
                    $(document.body).append($compile(data)($scope));
                    $('#sign-up1').modal('show');
                });
            }
            $scope.loginModal = function () {
                if ($("#sign-up1").length > 0) {
                    $('#sign-up1').modal('hide');
                }
                console.log(">>>>>>>>>>>>in login")
                $http.get(HTML.LOGIN, {cache: $templateCache}).success(function (data) {
                    console.log(">>>>>>>>>>>...data is>>>>>.", data);
                    $(document.body).append($compile(data)($scope));
                    $('#login-popup').modal('show');
                });
            }

        },


    };
    return directive;
})
```

**Error**

> angular.js:13708 TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object

Comment: Can you please post a plunker and a detailed stack trace? That would help better!

Comment: @Srijith...... i want to confirm one thing. once i call the loginModal function from directive and  the function compile the template data and append it to body .again i call the RegistrationModal function from the same directive should i destroy the scope or anything else

Comment: If you want to use modal in your project, I would recommend to use  [ui-bootstrap](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/)

Comment: @Emidomh..sorry but this is not a modal related issue.and this is a common functionality in my project.i can't change .

Answer (score 0):

What is `HTML` object? You use it as a global variable so it's probably out of a scope.

You should inject all such things as services or constant.

Comment: .....HTML object is a part of constant  services.issue is not related to this...i think when i am again binding scope when compile issue may to related to this line  $(document.body).append($compile(data)($scope)) .

Comment: So which line from this excerpt gives an error?

PS. You shouldn't use Angular and jQuery together.